# Determine limit if the function diverges

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

How do we prove $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)=\infty\Rightarrow\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{f(x)}=0$$
I'm thinking of using the definition of a diverging limit to prove it: I will pick a random $m$, that $$f(x) > m$$
Then what do I do next? Is there anything else that I can know from the fact the limit of $f(x)$ diverges?

Comment: First step of a proof: make sure you understand what all the terms mean. What does $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)=\infty$ mean?

Comment: Write out the definition you used for $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) $ and note that $f(x) > m$ implies $\frac1m>\frac1{f(x)}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes your idea is fine, proceeding by definition we have that

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)=\infty \iff \forall m>0 \quad \exists x_0 \quad \forall x\ge x_0 \quad f(x)\ge m$$

and then

$$ \forall \varepsilon = \frac 1m>0 \quad \exists x_0 \quad \forall x\ge x_0 \quad \frac1{f(x)}\le \frac 1m=\varepsilon$$

Comment: thanks. So when you used epsilon you assumed that the limit converges right?

Comment: The last line is indeed the definition of limit.